# next_posts_link() always generates second page link on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pagination

Here is the code I'm using.

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$portfolios = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $portfolios->have_posts() ) : $portfolios->the_post(); 
  // Title, content and stuff...
endwhile;

next_posts_link( esc_html__( 'Load more', 'text-domain'), $portfolios->max_num_pages );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Let's assume we have 15 portfolios. The function generates links like below.

Page 1: SITE_ADDRESS/page/2

Page 2: SITE_ADDRESS/page/2

Page 3: SITE_ADDRESS/page/2

Page 4: Nothing

However, `$paged` and `$portfolios->max_num_pages` return right values all the time. Any idea why this is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

`get_query_var('paged')` instead of `get_query_var('page')`

```
  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

hope this will help!